# Checkbox causes error in Widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

I was trying to use Checkbox in Widget. Bug when it's defined in the layout, the widget shows "Problem loading Widget". There is an exception like "error inflating class". Does it mean there are some limits in using checkbox in widget or did I do something wrong?

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "Widget" you mean "App Widget", then the problem may be that RemoteViews don't support CheckBoxes.

Take a look at the "Creating the App Widget Layout" section in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Yes, here is the detail. Thanks a lot.

Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with Declaring Layout in XML. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget.